# The words of the jinns from the 72 Surah

Tags: quran, tafseer

> And that our foolish one [i.e., Iblees] has been saying about Allah an
> excessive transgression. And we had thought that mankind and the jinn
> would never speak about Allah a lie. ([72] Al-Jinn : 4-5)

My question is: if there were various religious movements among them, then why they believe that no one would lie about Allah?

Someone knowledgeable answer, please.

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, sorry a bit confused on what you are asking. Are you asking how come a group of the jinns mentioning about how another group of jinns could lie about ALLAAH (Glory Be To Him)?

Comment: @Ahmed, Va alaykum assalam, I ask why, knowing about the existence of various religious sects, they say that they trusted every word about Allah?

Answer (score 1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you and your family are doing well. So with regards to Surah Jinn we can break down each ayats (verses) from 1 through 15.

**Verses 1 through 3:** Mention a group of jinns (not all of them) that listened to the message of Islam and found that they were on the wrong path.

**Verses 4 through 7:** And those that were on different ways (paths) talked about ALLAAH (Glory Be to Him) in a wrong light. Just like what Christians and Jews do today. And when they recognized the truth it was shocking to them that how come they lied or mixed lie with truth to us and fed that to us. So for example you see that Christians they say son of GOD but they do good works but the main belief is corrupt.

**Verses 8 through 10**: Those groups of jinns that went to eavesdrop on what was happening in the lowest of heavens now find that they are guarded. The question should come why? Because they did listen to the truth but they mixed it with falsehood. Why? For gain , for money. Why did Pharaoh say he was GOD because his ego was inflated and he wanted power and wanted to rule the people. In verse 10 you will see that what they eavesdropped was what pertained to things that were going to happen to the people or jinns on earth.

**Verse 11:** Describes different groups that were made. Some even knowing the truth changed the truth for power or for some other reason. You can see this even in human history how historical facts are changed to gain leverage over others or have it favor them. Even during the Prophet Muhammad (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him) that the other people said why is he chosen to be Prophet. Although if they were chosen then they would have been happy with it. So jealousy, greed, fame, power, etc. are found within jinns and humans. That is how ibless got expelled from the heavens due to his arrogance and pride.

**Verses 12 through 13:** The group that listened / eavesdropped now realize the power of ALLAAH (Glory Be To Him). It happens to people on earth that they forget about GOD and then when a earthquake happens or some great catastrophe then they say I am sorry and I forgot about the majestic power of GOD.

**Verse 14** Now those who have listened they obeyed and are Muslim. And there are those who are still defiant and are unbelievers.

Overall you see that just because you know the truth does not mean you will follow it. You see this with iblees that he knows who is GOD and he knows what he is doing is wrong. But due to his ego he will not accept it and is taking out his anger and wrongdoings on the humans and other jinns.

With humans there are many examples throughout history that people are hopeful and think good of others even their own families. But then something regarding their family (say they are a murderer or done some other crime) and the family members are shocked. They mention they were normal or good and we cannot believe they did such a horrible crime. So likewise the group of jinns that accepted the veils of wrong information from other jinns was uplifted. And we also have to remember not all jinns have the same capabilities. Some are stronger. Some have more knowledge than others. Some are leaders and most of ruled. There is a hidden system and their food and lifestyle is different than ours. However, there is belief and good Muslim jinns as well.

**If you need further explanation on any of the verses please let me know.**

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.

Comment: My response will have to be broken apart because the character limit on each comment. 

Main verse on which the discussion is about:

"And we had thought that mankind and the jinn would never speak about ALLAAH a lie."

First Possibility: They know there are other religious groups. The statement is just an informational/reflective verse reflecting their thought. Like I know people kill each other. But when I reflect I say to myself I would have never thought that people would kill each other. How could they do this? What is wrong with them? The should know better. These thoughts come.

Comment: Second possibility: they (meaning this group of jinns) thought that each of the religions were right in their own ways. Like each to his own way and all ways are good ways. The same happens in today's society where people believe that all paths of spirituality are good paths and lead to GOD. But that is a fallacy. So when the Quran was revealed to them the recognized there is only true path and all other paths are false and then the were reflective and surprised as how could others speak about ALLAAH such a lie.

Comment: Third possibility: they are isolated jinn group that were not communication with other religious groups. Within themselves they had good (according to them) and bad (according to them). Like the christian people within their religion they view some as being devout and others on different paths ways (rebellious, factions, beliefs mixed in), etc. Also isolated group happens in the human world. There are groups of humans even today that don't know about the outside world. This has happened throughout human history as well.

Comment: I think the first two options are more likely. Anyway, your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a scholar and I do not agree on religion, but submission and submission to Islam is a duty
Otherwise, how can we call ourselves Muslims?
I also use a translation tool that may distort the meaning I want to convey to you

1 Yes, of course, jinn are like humans, and that is why you find among them people of different religions, and if you know magicians who have been cursed by God or ruqya, then they must do this to you.
2 Not all jinn can eavesdrop on angels, and these jinn may be among those who cannot listen because jinn have different abilities.
3 It is possible that the jinn who were listening to the Messenger were from one or different sect, just like children who do not believe that their parents are lying to them when they tell them information.
They also believed that their masters, humans and jinn, would not lie about God, and God knows best